# How to Update mysql object included data with JSON_SET

Tags: mysql, node.js

I Cant update mysql properly that include objects.

my table  name aaaaa
my column name bbbbb

my CODE is below :

```
const data = [
{ colum: 0, contents: [ 601, 602 ] },
{ colum: 1, contents: [ 603 ] },
{ colum: 2, contents: [ 604 ] },
{ colum: 3, contents: [ 605 ] },
{ colum: 4, contents: [ 606 ] },
{ colum: 5, contents: [ 607 ] },
{ colum: 6, contents: [ 608 ] },
{ colum: 7, contents: [ 609 ] },    
{ colum: 8, contents: [ 610 ] },
{ colum: 9, contents: [ 611 ] },     
{ colum: 10, contents: [ 616, 615 ] }
]
    

var STRINGCONTENT = JSON.stringify(data);

connection.query(`UPDATE aaaaa SET bbbbb = JSON_SET(bbbbb, '$.updatethat', ?) WHERE id = ?`,[STRINGCONTENT,MYID],function (error, result) {
if (error) {return res.status(500).send({ message: false, code: "errormessage" })}

})
```

Results always like that

```
{
    "yyy": [], 
    "updatethat": "[{\"colum\":0,\"contents\":[601,602]},{\"colum\":1,\"contents\":[603]},{\"colum\":2,\"contents\":[604]},{\"colum\":3,\"contents\":[605]},{\"colum\":4,\"contents\":[606]},{\"colum\":5,\"contents\":[607]},{\"colum\":6,\"contents\":[609]},{\"colum\":7,\"contents\":[608,610]},{\"colum\":8,\"contents\":[611]},{\"colum\":9,\"contents\":[615]},{\"colum\":10,\"contents\":[616]}]", 
    "cccc": [], 
    "mmm": [], 
    "nnnn": []
}
```

but I dont want "" signs...

What I trieds :

```
bbbbb = JSON_SET(bbbbb, '$.updatethat', JSON_OBJECT(?))
bbbbb = JSON_SET(bbbbb, '$.updatethat', JSON_ARRAY(?))
bbbbb = JSON_SET(bbbbb, '$.updatethat', ?)
```

Alsa tried directly "data" without convert string...

I thought maybe there is mysql problem and I directly tried to insert data to column with that

```
bbbbb = ?
```

this worked correctly

but that is not  I want I just tried database.. Mydatabase column type longtext...

Comment: Hello, it is not necessary to SHOUT at us, All CAPS is considered shouting

Comment: ok I update title.. thanks...